# How to compare a symbol with string in Gasm (Gnu Assembler)?

Tags: linux, assembly, gnu

I need to count amount of spaces in string using gasm. So, I have written with simple program, but comparison doesn't work.

```
.section .data
  str:
    .string " TEst   string wit h spaces   \n"

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:

movl $0,%eax # %eax - amount of spaces
movl $0,%ecx # Starting our counter with zero

loop_start:
  cmpl $32,str(,%ecx,1)  # Comparison (this is never true)
  jne sp
  incl %eax # Programm never goes there
  incl %ecx
  jmp loop_start
sp:
  cmpl $0X0A,str(,%ecx,1) #Comparison for the end of string
  je loop_end #Leaving loop if it is the end of string
  incl %ecx
  jmp loop_start
loop_end:
  movl (%eax),%ecx  # Writing amount of spaces to %ecx
  movl $4,%eax
  movl $1,%ebx
  movl $2,%edx
  int $0x80

  movl $1,%eax
  movl $0,%ebx
  int $0x80
```

So, problem in this string `cmpl $32,str(,%ecx,1)` There I try to compare space (32 in ASCII) with 1 byte of str (I use %ecx as a counter for displacement, and took 1 byte). Unfortunately, I haven't found any example in Internet about symbol comparison in Gasm. I've tried to use gcc generated code, but I can't understand and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This never returns true, and I think I know why:

```
cmpl $32,str(,%ecx,1)
```

Because you're comparing an immediate value with a memory address, the assembler has no way of knowing the size of the two operands. So, it's probably assuming each argument is 32 bits, but you want to compare two 8-bit values. You need some way to explicitly state that you're comparing bytes. My solution for that would be:

```
mov str(,%ecx,1), %dl  # move the byte at (str+offset) into 'dl'
cmp $32, %dl           # compare the byte 32 with the byte 'dl'.
# hooray, now we're comparing the two bytes!
```

There is probably a better way to explicitly compare bytes, and I probably made a stupid mistake somewhere; I'm not too familiar with AT&T syntax. But, you should get the idea of what your problem is, and how it can be solved.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now I understand that gcc was doing the same, however, it was hard to understand, because it translated code     `for (i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        if (str[i]==' ') a++;
    }` into `.L4:
 movl -8(%rbp), %eax
 cltq
 movzbl -112(%rbp,%rax), %eax
 cmpb $32, %al
 jne .L3
 addl $1, -4(%rbp)
.L3:
 addl $1, -8(%rbp)`

Comment: GAS doesn't have to assume anything; `cmpl` is explicitly 32-bit operand size.  That's what the `l` suffix means in AT&T syntax.  `cmpb $' ', str(%ecx)` would be a byte compar.